# Getting a basemap in GDA94/MGA55

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, australia

I'm working in QGIS. My project CRS is set to EPSG: 28355 (GDA94/MGA 55). Whenever I import basemaps they are automatically in EPSG: 4283 (just GDA94). When I try and change the CRS of the basemap to EPSG28355 it doesn't work, and the basemap ends up squished somewhere over the other side of the world.

This is difficult, as all my data needs to be in MGA55 so it can be viewed by other people. How can I get a NSW basemap that displays in MGA55?

Comment: What do you mean by basemap?

Comment: Please read [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383434/changing-shapefiles-from-a-geographic-coordinate-system-to-a-projected-coordinat/383437#383437) when it comes to setting CRS of layers. Also, are you aware QGIS is able of on-the-fly reprojection, so you actually don't have to reproject anything manually.

Comment: Don't change the CRS of your basemap, but the CRS of your project.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a layer which is already in mga55.
2. Check project crs is in mga 55
3. load in the basemap. Dont change basemap crs.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I have been doing. The issue is that when I send a shapefile (polygon for example) to someone else using a basemap with a different crs, the shapefile is not located where i mapped it on my own basemap (in gda94)

Comment: When you write the shapefile, qgis will write a .prj file. You can open this file in a text editor (like notepad). Can you confirm if the .prj file exists and if the projection in it states MGA55 GDA94

Comment: Yep, the prj file exists! This is what it says: PROJCS["GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_55",GEOGCS["GCS_GDA_1994",DATUM["D_GDA_1994",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",10000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",147.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the issue does not seem to be on your end anymore. If your project and layer CRS is MGA55, your basemap will be reprojected (stick to the default 4283) and all your data will be in the correct location. I would ask the other person to load a blank QGIS project, load the shape file, then set the project CRS to MGA 55. Finally add the basemap. It should work (you can test this on your own machine before you send it out)!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If you could please accept my answer, that would be great. Btw do you work in civil / stormwater engineering?