# QGIS Line Buffer doesn't work

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-processing, buffer

I want to do positional accuracy analysis by using QGIS 3.16, thus I need to do buffer zone around the vector layer (I am using buffer in geoprocessing tools). However, the result of buffer always thousands of buffer zone. I have followed the guide to do buffer line from a video on youtube, in the video, it said I have to click on 'selected features only'. But, the problem is I cannot click it.

here's my file that I am working on.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YKAkvkTtudvw_jVYKL9cKICAW_2_akKm/view?usp=sharing

Any suggestion?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127530/discussion-on-question-by-rui-qgis-line-buffer-doesnt-work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a projection problem: the layer in `EPSG:32750` you try to buffer lies somewhere in Antarctica. You layer (originally in geographic CRS `EPSG:4326`) was not correctly reprojected - I guess you simply changed the layer's CRS instead. See here [why not to do that](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814). Setting/changing layer CRS very often gets confused with reprojection, but that are two completely different things.

Take your initiation layer in `EPSG:4326` and reproject it: `right-click layer / Export / Save Features As...` and there, select `EPSG:32750`. On this layer, run the buffer tool.

*Screenshot: reproject using the export option. See also the correctly created buffers on the map in the background:*
[image]