# Raster is in the wrong place, upon warping it dissappears in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, dem

I assigned a Raster image to its designated projection, it reappears 500 miles away. I tried to assign different projections, it goes off to another random place. I reproject it a variety of CRS's, georeference, it disappears every time on the map and the elevation in the legend varies from a large negative to the same large positive number.

The extent says it's in the proper place but on the map, it is displayed far from where it should be.

How do I get this raster where it needs to be?

Comment: As a general rule, it is a mistake to "assign" a projection to data which already has a coordinate reference defined.  Assigning different projections *should* cause the data to appear in random places (unless it's the original correct reference). Your first goal should be to restore or reacquire the original  dataset. If it aligns correctly with other data, and isn't in the CRS or the other data, you can project to that CRS.  If it doesn't align correctly, then you have a mystery on your hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **not** "assign" any CRS (normally): that will change the definition of the CRS and the coordinates will be interpreted in the wrong way - see for details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814. Once set a wrong CRS, reprojecting will not help, but transform the error to other projections.

Normally, QGIS takes care of interpreting the data automatically and put it in the correct place, you don't have to intervene manually - or just if the assigned projection is wrong (or missing).

What you should do: get the CRS-definition of the original file and (this time indeed) *set* the CRS back to this definition (`right click on your layer/Layer CRS/Set Layer CRS`). It's difficult to say which one this is: look up in your data (or - as you mentioned in your comment to this answer): compare to other data from the same source and get the CRS definition from there.

Comment: It worked! I had another file of the same area that had the exact same extent as the erroneous file but was in the correct place. I went to set layer to CRS like you said, using the projection of the other correct file and it lined up perfectly, Thank you!