# QGIS layer not visible

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, basemap

I have the following issue:

Project CRS is set to EPSG:9473

3 layers are loaded:

2 vector layers - one shapefile and one gpkg file Both have CRS assigned the same and listed in Layer Properties: EPSG:9473 - GDA2020 / Australian Albers - Projected

XYZ Tile - Bing Maps EPSG:9473 - GDA2020 / Australian Albers - Projected

All 3 layers are checked to visible.

The 2 vector layers align and overlay in the same position. The Bing Maps layer is not visible at all under the vectors. When "zoom to layer" is chosen the bing map layer loads, but the vectors are nowhere on it.

I have tried numerous different fixes and none work.

Answer (score 6):

Right click on Bing Maps layer and set CRS back to `EPSG:3857`. If you changed the layer CRS of the other layers, you'll have to repeat it there, too and get the initial CRS back.

Do **not** change layer CRS: your coordinate values will be interpreted in a wrong way ([see here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814)). If you load layers, QGIS will automatically (on the fly) project them on the map canvas in the CRS/projection you chose as project CRS.

Comment: Ok thanks I will take a look and may be back with some clarification questions.

Comment: Every layer has to be assigned the CRS that the data is saved in. Webmaps normally are saved in `EPSG:3857`, so if you manually tell QGIS to interpret the coordinate values in another definition, it will get project it in a wrong place. Same is true for every layer: do not change a layer CRS: if you want to have the layers in another projection (e.g. for Geoprocessing), **reproject** the layer. You need `set layer CRS` only if your layer does not have assigned any CRS definition or the wrong one.