# QGIS QNEAT3 Iso-Area as Interpolation (from Layer) - error regarding projected coordinate system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-plugins

I am new to QGIS and I want to create Iso-areas using the "Iso-Area as Interpolation (from Layer)" tool from the QNEAT3 Plugin to visualize areas dependent on the distance to a layer. I used various projected coordinate systems such as EPSG:3857 or EPSG:32700, however, I still always receive the following error code:

```
 The TIN-Interpolation algorithm in QGIS is designed to work with projected coordinate systems. Please use a projected coordinate system (eg. UTM zones) instead of geographic coordinate systems (eg. WGS84)!
```

Also already found this post: [Changing shapefiles from geographic (WGS84) to projected (EPSG:2263) coordinate system using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383434/changing-shapefiles-from-geographic-wgs84-to-projected-epsg2263-coordinate) addressing the same problem, however I still don't get it solved.

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure that all your layers (networklayer, pointlayer) are in a projected coordinate system, not only the projects coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Tested it by only loading the network layer and the point layer (both in EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator) in a new project, but still got the same error code. Happens both in QGIS 3.22.1 as well as QGIS 3.16.11. Any more ideas?

Comment: I just tested it with  OSM roadlayer projected into EPSG:3857 and a pointlayer also in 3857 with QGIS 3.22.1 and encountered no error - just as information. Please retry it with a new profile (settings->user profiles->new profile) and if you want, you can download my testdata (https://files.wheregroup.com/index.php/s/omfMWo5YzbNQNEW)

Comment: creating a new profile did the trick! Thanks a lot also for the testdata! Danke :)

Comment: so I will post it as an answer, if you want you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested it with OSM roadlayer projected into EPSG:3857 and a pointlayer also in 3857 with QGIS 3.22.1 and encountered no error - just as information.

Please retry it with a new profile: settings->user profiles->new profile and if you want, you can download my testdata (https://files.wheregroup.com/index.php/s/omfMWo5YzbNQNEW)