# Buffer problem (WGS84)

Tags: qgis, buffer, wgs84

I have a point layer with the  CRS WGS84, and if I put in other CRS, my points move to another world side. So, how could I do the buffer?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are buffering the points by 100000 degrees. Which could explain the weird result. 

What buffer distance do you want? If it’s a measured distance (metres, feet etc.) reproject your points into a projection system in the same units. The buffer should then work as intended.

Comment: I suppose that comma acts as a decimal separator with users locale settings and buffer is only 10 degrees. It still corresponds roughly to 1200 kilometers that is probably more than expected.

Comment: I think that you have to reproject your Layer to a projected coordinate system, like UTM, so you can have the distances im meters or feets. Changing it will make the buffer have a right result.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options:

1. Reproject you layer to CRS suitable for measuring distances like UTM as proposed in the comments you got. Be aware **not to change (set) CRS**, but to **really reproject** ([see here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814)).
2. Create a buffer using QGIS expressions with [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) ([see here for details and the differences between these options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)). Use this expression make replacements as indicated:

```
    transform (
        buffer (
            transform (
                $geometry, 
                'EPSG:4326',
                'EPSG:2056' --replace 2056 with an appropriate CRS for your case
            ),
            2000 -- replace 2000 with the buffer-distance you like
        ),
        'EPSG:2056', --replace 2056 with an appropriate CRS for your case
        'EPSG:4326'
    )
```