# Transformation from ETRS89/EPSG:3416 to ETRS89/EPSG:3035

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, epsg

I have already worked with the first KBS, but now I need to convert my whole system to EPSG:3035. I imported this system to my QGIS, and tried to convert everything, but now my lines/polygons are far away of my original positions.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you try to convert your data in QGIS?

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between **reprojecting** and **changing CRS**? I guess you entered this trap. See here for details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814

Comment: Can you right click on the layer and get to the menu item "Set Layer CRS"?  you can pick the crs that the data is supposed to be in.