# Georeferencing using coordinates always corresponds to wrong location on reference map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, georeferencing

This is the map that I tried to georeference using its coordinates, e. g. -98.00 E and 16.00 N

[image]

Both maps are on the same projection. However, no matter what coordinates I enter, they always correspond to a location in the Gulf of Guinea:

[image]

Even though it should be in Mexico!

What am I doing wrong?

I'm new to QGIS.

[image]

Comment: Why Gulf of Guinea? Because it's Null Island. See here for details and better understand the background and why you must change CRS as mentioned in the answer by @swiss_knight https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you want to change your target CRS to [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84.html) because your target coordinates are given in latitudes and longitudes, not as web Mercator coordinates ([EPSG:3857](https://epsg.org/crs_3857/WGS-84-Pseudo-Mercator.html)) which you are currently using in your "Transformation Settings" window.

As a dummy illustration, this is a [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) equivalent of what you are currently doing:

[image]

Whereas you want this:

[image]

The difference lies in the CRS of the input point. In the first case, it is set to `EPSG:3857` and the result on a WGS84 (`EPSG:4326`) map is in the Gulf of Guinea.
But in the second case, the CRS of the input point is `EPSG:4326`, and well, this is useless, but I kept the reprojection step, it's displayed where it must lie, in central America.