# OSM base map is not showing up in QField app. In QGIS, layers CRS is EPSG 4326 and basemap CRS by default comes EPSG 3857. Is it the reason?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qfield, basemap

OSM base map is not showing up in QField app. Is this because of the following reason -

Layers CRS is EPSG 4326 and OSM basemap CRS by default comes EPSG 3857, When CRS is set to EPSG 4326 basemap moves. Project CRS is set to EPSG 4326

As a result it does not load in QField app. What is the solution?

I tried setting a new QGIS file to EPSG 4326 and add basemap still same result.

Comment: Read this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383434/changing-shapefiles-from-geographic-wgs84-to-projected-epsg2263-coordinate/383437#383437

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can you please tell me why is it not loading in Qfield app. What can I do?