# Map a raster data set with polar stereographic projection with other data sets in UTM projection

Tags: coordinate-system, utm

I need to clip a vector data set to a precipitation data set which has been provided in a polar geographic projection. I tried the Warp function to reproject the raster, entering polar stereographic as source CRS and UTM zone 33N as target and other way round. However, the polar stereographic data set is not compatible with my vector data set in terms of CRS and is shown in a different location on OSM. I am therefore unable to clip the raster data set to my study area.

Picture: left hand side vector data set, right the raster data set with stereographic projections

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! It looks like you have a coordinate system problem, see if any of the suggestions at https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/ help.

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814

Comment: Minimum, it looks like you have the wrong central meridian/longitude of origin for your definition.