# How to define (not reproject) a CRS of a shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a shapefile which comes with a wrong CRS and I would like to redefine the projection, so WITHOUT applying some transformation on the coordinates.
In ArcMap you can do this with the 'Define Projection'-Tool.Is there a some tool in QGIS, which redefines the projection?
I only find the reprojection function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is two tool for that (the first one create a copy of your layer, the second one create (or overwrite an already existing) projection):

- **Assign projection**

> This algorithm assigns a new projection to a vector layer.
>
> It creates a new layer with the exact same features and    geometries
> as the input one, but assigned to a new CRS. E.g. the    geometries
> are not reprojected, they are just assigned to a different    CRS.
> This algorithm can be used to repair layers which have been
> assigned an incorrect projection. Attributes are not modified by this
> algorithm.

- **Define Shapefile projection**

> This algorithm sets an existing Shapefile's projection to the provided
> CRS. Contrary to the "Assign    projection" algorithm, it will not
> output a new layer. The .prj and    .qpj files associated with the
> Shapefile will be overwritten - or    created if missing - to match
> the provided CRS.

Answer (score 7):

Simply right-click the layer in the Layers panel > `Layer CRS` > `Set Layer CRS...` - no new layer will be created, simply a new CRS definition is assigned to the layer in QGIS (the data itself remains unchanged).

The do this for several layers at once, select the, then click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

---

**Remark**: Be careful [**never** to use this when you want in fact to reproject](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814) a layer, as this is a very common trap that all too many users fall into.

If you assign a wrong CRS, the layer will be misplaced and the features appear somewhere else on the Earth. So only use this if you are sure which CRS to assign as a layer with wrong CRS definition is of no use.

*A shapefile with the countries of the world, created in `EPSG:4326`, with a (wrong) CRS definition `EPSG:21781` suddenly appears in southwestern France, near Bordeaux:*
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I did find the function for my purpose: In QGIS there is the function 'Assign projection' which is described as :

```
"This algorithm assigns a new projection to a vector layer. 
It creates a new layer with the exact same features and geometries as the input one, 
but assigned to a new CRS. E.g. the geometries are not reprojected, 
they are just assigned to a different CRS. 
This algorithm can be used to repair layers which have been assigned an incorrect projection.
Attributes are not modified by this algorithm."
```