Vector layer still misaligned after reprojecting
I'm new to QGIS, and trying to figure out why my vector layers are still misaligned after reprojecting.
I am using ESRI topographic basemap EPSG:3857 WGS 84
Two datasets I have overlayed display marine protected areas and coastal seagrass distribution in The Solomon Islands. The MPA layer has the same CRS as the project, EPSG 3857 WGS 84 but is misaligned.
The Seagrass layer has the CRS ESRI:54009 - World Mollweide
I have tried to re-assign the CRS of both layers to various kinds including EPSG:4326 WGS 84 (as I have further layers which are correctly aligned with this CRS)
I have also tried to re-project the layers via processing>toolbox>reproject layer and by exporting and changing the CRS.
I have read this could be due to low accuracy within the layer datasets themselves and that there is little to do to fix this. What can I do?



You're probably encountering the most often asked problem here on this site: layers that do not allign basemaps. Im ca. 99% of cases, peoply simply use "set CRS" instead of reprojecting, because they don't know the difference. As a general rule: never use set CRS if you're not 100% sure what you do. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/483065/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814

Re-assigning CRS is almost always wrong, and only likely to make things bad enough to need to start over with the original data. Some data just doesn't and won't ever align. You should [Edit] the Question to contain a screenshot and quantify the distances involved.

Apart from telling us if "missalign" means like 10 cm or 1000 km, it would also help if you described in a step-by-step manner what you do, from the moment you open QGIS, until the moment where a problem (which one?) appears.

Thank you all for your feedback. I have added screenshots above to show the extent of the missalignment of the seagrass and MPA layers. This is how both layers load from the data source. I have tried reprojecting via toolbox as well as export>save features as however the layers appear the exact same regardless of the CRS. Hope this helps to clarify. Thanks again!
