Polygon misalignment issue
I've been tasked with coming up with a flood evacuation plan for a neighborhood, but the shapefile I've been given has misaligned polygons. The layer CRS is EPSG:3380 - GDM2000/Selangor Grid
Any ideas on how to fix this?


What projection are your shapefiles in? - please add this info to your question and is an transformation done when you load the shapefile? see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/276

Sometimes there isn't any fix possible, just poorly registered data from different sources. It would help if you could [Edit] the Question to address the lineage of the data presented together.

In this context, "lineage" of data is the source of the data, e.g., municipal government  for layer A and World Factbook for layer B. If the sources of the data are poorly conflated, it might be because they never shared a common reference dataset.
