Layers do not align / are shown in the wrong location
I am currently using QGIS 3.34.3.
I have a set of different data (vector as well as raster) that should be located in Central Europe.
However, only one of the datasets is shown there (a DEM from a different source). The rest is displayed in the Caucasus region or Central Asia.
I reprojected all datasets to UTM (EPSG:25832), and the project coordinate system is also UTM (EPSG:25832).
Despite this, the layers do not align.
I checked the layers extent. The northing values of the misaligned layers seem realistic, but the easting values are far too high.
Some of the layers appear to align correctly in Central Asia, even if they should be in Central Europe.
(Edit: Could be important to note that the data was produced with an GNSS-device. If I load it into QGIS without creating a new project and look for the CRS it just shows me this: 
and this:


Did you reproject them, or just change the CRS?

Thanks for your answer! I tried the reproject layer tool (vector general) and I tried changing the CRS (properties--> source--> assigned Coordinate Reference System). Any ideas what could be wrong? Im new to QGIS, never had a similiar problem in ArcGIS.

You did not, in fact, reproject the data; what you did was corrupt the projection metadata of the original dataset (never assign or define unless you know the original definition is incorrect). If it's any consolation, this is the most frequently asked Question posted here. You need to go back to original sources and see if they align, to see if the original projections are corrupt, and work from there.

Based on fact that the data is appearing too far east, the data may be using a GK (Gauss-Kruger) zone where the false easting is prefixed with the zone number 33 like a GK or UTM zone normally with a false easting of 500000 is instead 33500000.

See here for details to understand what went wrong in your case: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814
